# Need help setting up Visual Studio for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, visual

I would like to start creating solutions for `Office 365 (SharePoint Online)`, is there a guide to setup `Visual Studio`?

i'm following some tutorials online, but they have options that i do not have when creating a new project?

Comment: check these links http://thomasbartsch.net/sharepoint-development-with-visual-studio-community-2015/       (2) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2tx7z6d.aspx  (3) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179924.aspx

Comment: what are those options , you dont have. please explain your current env. briefly.

Comment: One of them was a webpart - i need to create a map using google API and would like to implement that webpart as a solution. I currently have a fresh install of Visual Studio Community 2015.

Answer (score 1):

You should take approach of developing Add-in's for SharePoint. This is recommended for SharePoint Online. Follow below url from MSDN to learn more about SharePoint Add-in's.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179930.aspx